# How to do not repeat a razor code in an ASP.NET MVC "edit" view for each model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

If you use ASP.NET MVC, then the following code must be familiar to you:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-sm-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.att)
    </div>
    <div class="form-sm-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.att, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.att)
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a basic input group set with label, input and validation message.

Today I'm facing a POCO class with dozens of attributes. I mean It has N number of properties in model class. In order to build a HTML he has to repeat above code snippet N times. If there is change in DOM he has to manually change all CSS class or even certain HTML.

I am looking for a solution wherein he don't have to repeat above code snippet for dozens of model propeties.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please give a sample of the model class.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by change dozens of attributes? You mean htmlAttributes or a property in the object?

Comment: I guess OP means he has **N** number of properties in model class. In order to build a HTML he has to repeat above code snippet **N** times. If there is change in DOM he has to manually change all CSS class or even certain HTML. He is looking for a solution wherein he don't have to repeat above code snippet for dozens of model propeties.

Comment: Thanks, I wil add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create classes:

```
public static class PropertyExtensions
{
    public static ModelWrapper<T> Wrap<T>(this T property, string propertyName)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(ModelWrapper<>);
        var specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));

        var wrappedPropertyModel = (ModelWrapper<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(specificType);

        wrappedPropertyModel.ModelProperty = property;
        wrappedPropertyModel.PropertyName = propertyName;

        return wrappedPropertyModel;
    }
}

public class ModelWrapper<T>
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public T ModelProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Create a partial view:

```
@model ModelWrapper<object>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-sm-4">
        @Html.Label(Model.PropertyName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-sm-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelProperty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ModelProperty)
    </div>
</div>
```

In the main View:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialViewName", ((object)Model.YourVariableProperty).Wrap("YourVariableProperty"))
```